# One to One Qry mapping

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying a quite simple mapping using Dapper. It is kind of One to One result set. Here is the simplified version of what I would like to do:

Classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

I get the data from a View/Strored Proc like this:

```
SELECT street, name, lastname, town from someProc
```

Is there a way to map this in one step, maybe like this?

```
//trying to get a List of Persons including mapped Addresses
connection.Query<Person>()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would just create a third class containing the fields you want, then query for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself... So for those googling this:

Combine Dapper.Mapper (NuGet package) and a SplitOn field in your result set.

The result data should be ordered by objects (columnwise) and you can either use an Id or a "virtual field" ('' as id) as a splitter.

The "3rd object" idea is stupid.